# Angular portlet throws exception path does not start with a "/" character

Tags: liferay-7

On Liferay github there is sample portlet which uses Angular https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/gradle/apps/npm/angular-npm-portlet

I've created my own portlet using maven command  `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=liferay` 
choose: 12

and after that I've built it and deployed to tomcat and exception was thrown:
 
`07:29:02,097 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2][ComboServlet:89] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path samplePortlet@1.0.0.js does not start with a "/" character`

any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you run the generate command and then you try to do `mvn clean install`. The error is a cryptic one but one of the cases that you can get it is when the combo servlet can't find the dependency in the jar file. There is not yet a maven wrapper for the npm functionality.

You can do 2 things.

Without gradle:

- `mvn clean install`
- `npm run build`
- copy the js from **build** folder into the **target** folder. `cp -R build/resources/main/META-INF/resources/ target/classes/META-INF/resources/`
- `mvn install` (don't clean!)

With gradle:

`gradle build`

Few remarks:

- If you want to work with the npm stuff I suggest that you go for Liferay workspace, blade tools and Gradle combinations. It works smoother.
- When you create the project with the archetype you might need to fix the ID for the component. In the JS code will contain something with the artefact name - root but the actual id in the JSP will probably be just namespace.